# Using Content Query Webpart to pull back item from a Reusable Content List

Tags: reusable, list, content-query-web-part

Ok so I am currently trying to use a content query webpart to pull back an item from a reusable content list but it just doesn't seem to work when i use reusable html. Can someone please verify if that is possible? I am able to do it on an item which is storing a footer in the reusable text but it just doesn't seem to work for the reusable html.

Answer (score 1):

When things get at all complicated, I recommend switching from the CQWP to the Data View Web Part (DVWP).  It gives you far more capability and total control over the rendered output.

Answer (score 0):

It works. I posted a sample webpart to [this](/questions/3494/get-reusablehtml-from-reusable-content-via-content-query-webpart/4011#4011) question